# Update a Turbo stream as a global variable updates (Hotwire & Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I'm using Ruby On Rails and Hotwire (Turbo) to dynamically update my page with the user having to reload.

I have a global variable which is an array, and I'm looping through it on the page.
For example

```
<% $listNumberPlates.each { |item| %>
    <%= item %>
<% } %>
```

Now I want to update this (without reloading) whenever the variable changes.
To make it easier I do have a method that updates the variable.

I have tried using...

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "listNumberPlatesStream" %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "listNumberPlatesStream" do %>
```

But I don't know how I could update these. Any help or suggestion would be much appreicated.
Thank you.

Comment: I never used turbo though found a fantastic tuotorial that might help you answer your own question: https://www.colby.so/posts/turbo-frames-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

you could use something similiar like this:

```
  after_create_commit do
    broadcast_append_to [commentable, :comments], target: "#{dom_id(parent || commentable)}_comments", partial: 'comments/comment_with_replies', locals: { current_user: user }
  end

  after_update_commit do
    broadcast_replace_to self, partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { current_user: user }
  end

  after_destroy_commit do
    broadcast_action_to self, action: :remove, target: "#{dom_id(self)}_with_comments"
  end
```

in the view something like this should be in place:

```
= turbo_stream_from @session, :comments
  = tag.div id: "#{dom_id(@session)}_comments" do
    = render partial: "comments/comments", collection: @session.root_comments, as: :comment, locals: { current_user: current_user }
```

and have a look at the related methods `broadcast_action_to` and so on in the docs on in [github](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/app/models/concerns/turbo/broadcastable.rb)